# Redirect set -x / set -o xtrace to standard output

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I'm using `set -x` (also known as `set -o xtrace`) to log the commands and their arguments in my script that are executed. I find it problematic that the commands and their arguments are redirected to stderr. I need the stderr channel to store only real errors that's why using `./script.sh --arg ${ARG} 2>1` is not a solution. Is there a way to redirect to stdout commands and their arguments generated by the `set -x` command?

Comment: Some more answers can be found in https://serverfault.com/questions/296991/send-bash-x-output-to-logfile-without-interrupting-standard-output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`BASH_XTRACEFD`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) to redirect the trace output.

```
 BASH_XTRACEFD
          If set to an integer corresponding to a valid file
          descriptor, bash will write the trace output generated
          when set -x is enabled to that file descriptor.  The file
          descriptor is closed when BASH_XTRACEFD is unset or
          assigned a new value.  Unsetting BASH_XTRACEFD or
          assigning it the empty string causes the trace output to
          be sent to the standard error.  Note that setting
          BASH_XTRACEFD to 2 (the standard error file descriptor)
          and then unsetting it will result in the standard error
          being closed.
```

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 10> /tmp/xtrace
export BASH_XTRACEFD=10
...
# rest of the script
```

Comment: It seems like this output the commands to a file in /tmp. To answer OP's question, prepend `export BASH_XTRACEFD=1` before set +x and it will print to stdout

Comment: @Aaron_H, before `set -x`, right (not `+`)?